# Misconfigured App on Facebook but no errors?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I am trying to set up a tab with a link to a contact form from my site on Facebook.

I developed the 'app' through the developers site and have set up the page tab.

I've saved the app and it saves it fine (displaying a message saying changes were saved but it might take some time to propagate across all servers.)

Well I waited an hour and I still can't add the tab to my page. I tried locating the app page directly using the namespace, but I get an error message saying:

```
"[My App] cannot be displayed because the app is misconfigured."
```

I don't know how it is misconfigured? There are no errors when saving, so I don't know what the issue is or how to go about fixing it. There are no problems with the app that I can see... how am I supposed to know what's wrong with it?

All it is is a page tab. I've put the link to the page tab in, I don't have a secure page (https) so I have left this box blank but I don't know what to do now.

Any ideas how I can find out in what way it is 'misconfigured'?

Comment: can you navigate to the tab page directly outside of facebook? e.g http://mysite.com/tab.php . Does that display correctly or does that error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error usually occurs when you try to view the App Center page for the app when the app doesn't have the 'App Details' tab settings populated.

So instead of:

https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/APP_NAMESPACE

Make sure you are loading:

https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE

That page will display hints (if you are admin or developer of the app) on what you are missing.

Answer (score -1):

And, adding to the answer already given by @Donn Lee, which pointed to the right way, you must also ADD A PLATFORM in settings, in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP-ID/settings/