# cannot be displayed because the app is misconfigured

Tags: facebook

I am trying to integrate a job portal (runs on google app engine) in facebook.
I have done the required configuration by creating a app and adding web and facebook app platoforms.
When I click on App details (web preview) , the app loads fine.

Web preview - opens up the url

https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/jobs_for_java_skills?preview=1&locale=en_US

But after I share the application to public, when user clicks on shared item on timeline I get the below error.

Misconfigured App
Sorry, the details for Jobs4j cannot be displayed because the app is misconfigured.

The URL it generates ..

https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/jobs_for_java_skills

Where can I see the logs? what is the misconfiguration ?

Comment: Is your application in sandbox mode?

Comment: Its is live and available to all Users. It is not yet submitted for app center for review . I tried and I cannot it says app does meet enough rating and user base yet.but it is a new app..

Comment: That's not what I asked...

Comment: sorry where is this option?

Comment: Please try this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877733/misconfigured-app-on-facebook-but-no-errors

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings> Security Settings> Deactivate Account> and choose My account was Hacked> and Secure your account by giving new password and confirm email.
And get back to your account and check the hidden unapproved apps will be removed by facebook.